# How to move burstly ads to the center of the screen in android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, burstly

The MainActivity is extending UnityPlayerActivity.

We are using the following code snippet to place banner ads on android.

```
        FrameLayout layout1 = new FrameLayout(this);
        BurstlyAnimatedBanner levelUpBanner  = new BurstlyAnimatedBanner( this, layout1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), "0455184989016204562", "Level_Up_Screen", 30, false);
        LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        addContentView(layout1,lp1);
```

Doing this is showing the ads at the top-left corner of the screen. I need the ads at the top-center of the screen. I tried using layout1.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER); but that did not help. How can I achieve what I need? Also, I need to do this programatically and cannot use and xml.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the Burstly Unity plugin at github.com/Burstly/BurstlyUnityPlugin.

You can center the banner ad by adding it to a RelativeLayout instead of a FrameLayout as we do in the plugin:

```
mBaseLayout = new RelativeLayout(mActivity);
mBaseLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
mActivity.addContentView(mBaseLayout, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
lp.topMargin = (int)originY;
lp.leftMargin = (int)originX;
burstlyView.setLayoutParams(lp);

mBaseLayout.addView(burstlyView);
```

With this, you can then position the banner at will. If you wish to position it at the top center, then you'd want to change `lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT)` to `lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)`.